# AutoIT getting text with _Stringbeetwen and saving it to .txt file

Tags: string, autoit

so I need to get a text from this file in brackets

> Lance Hill (born February 17, 1972) is a retired U.S. soccer forward. He spent one season in USISL.

And save it to the Output.txt

```
Local $fArray
If NOT FileExists("C:\Users\fiwi\Desktop\Input.txt") Then
MsgBox(0, "Error", "Unable to open Exclusion File" & @CRLF & "It appears that the file does not exist.")
Exit
Else
   _FileReadToArray("C:\Users\fiwi\Desktop\update.txt", $fArray)
EndIf
local $check = _StringBetween( $fArray, "Comments" , "PDF" )
FileWrite("Output.txt", $check)
```

Mine script gives me a "0" in a output file.

Comment: Where ist Comments or PDF in your string?

Comment: _StringBetween returns an Array!

Comment: .. and the first parameter have to be a string, not an array

Comment: Then you can take the solution direct from the help file: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_StringBetween.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[_StringBetween](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_StringBetween.htm)

_StringBetween has strings as parameters and return an array.

This should work:

```
$fileContent = FileRead($file)
$array = _StringBetween($fileContent, "Comments" , "PDF")

For $i = 0 To Ubound($array)-1
    FileWriteLine("C:\Output.txt", $array[$i])
Next
```

And you are checking one file, and reading another.

```
If NOT FileExists("C:\Users\fiwi\Desktop\Input.txt") Then

_FileReadToArray("C:\Users\fiwi\Desktop\update.txt", $fArray)
```